# Calling MySQL Stored Procedure in Python - incorrect # of arguments error

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to access a stored procedure using Python where I enter enter in a customer ID, and it will render a multi-row table with the multiple instances a customer ate at a restaurant as well as what they ate, what time they ate it, and what month they ate it. It is a multi-row table since the customer ID is not the primary key.

Within SQL, entering in this command:

```
call metrics.GetFoodByCustomerID("115960981")
```

will render the correct table for me. However when I run the following function in Python, I am getting the error that I am entering the incorrect arguments for procedure.

[[image: enter image description here]]

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: In future, please don't post images of code.  Please copy and paste the text of your code into your question.  I wanted to copy a line of code from your question into my answer but I couldn't: I had to type it out manually.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `cursor.callproc`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.callproc) states that the second parameter `args` should be a

> Sequence of parameters to use with procedure

In your line

```
myCursor.callproc('metrics.GetFoodByCustomerID', ('115960981'))
```

you are passing in a string surrounded by parentheses for `args`.  The parentheses around `'115960981'` have no effect, in particular they don't turn this value into a 1-element sequence.  However, in Python, strings are sequences, so the parameter list is being interpreted as a sequence of 9 one-character strings.  The error arises because your stored procedure doesn't take 9 arguments.

Try replacing the above line with

```
myCursor.callproc('metrics.GetFoodByCustomerID', ('115960981',))
```

This is probably what you were aiming for.  Note the trailing comma, which makes the expression in parentheses into a 1-tuple.  Alternatively, use a list instead: you don't need a trailing comma in order to make a 1-element list:

```
myCursor.callproc('metrics.GetFoodByCustomerID', ['115960981'])
```

Comment: @ShabinaRayan: I don't know where you got the idea you could call `stored_results` on a cursor.  That attribute isn't mentioned on the documentation page I linked to, so frankly I'm not surprised you're getting that error.  Perhaps you want to use one of the `fetchall`, `fetchone` or `fetchmany` methods in the documentation I linked to?